# Simple php include() not working

Tags: php, html, include

I'm familiar with HTML but only just starting to learn php. I can't seem to figure out why this code isn't working. I've previously had no problems with include()'s but that is when the php code is it's own distinct file. This time around I'm trying to create a dynamic web page with php scripts. I have apache running with xampp and I have the gf.css file and testing.php in the same folder as the main html file.

The problem I can't seem to figure out is that nothing is showing up in the text box when I try and run the HTML page. It seems as though nothing in the php tags is running. I put in echo statements to try and determine what the problem was but nothing showed up unless, however, I placed a h1 tag after the first " in my echo statement. But inn this case, no matter where I placed the closing h1 tag, the rest of the php script just printed. It was as if I couldn't close the tag.

That's as much info as I can give really. Any help and/or explanations as to what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Here's the HTML file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='gf.css'>
        <body>
            <h1>This is my web page</h1>
            <div id='main_box'>
                <?php           
                    include ('testing.php');                 
                ?>
            </div>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Here's the .css file

```
#main_box
{
    height:500px;
    width:400px;
    color:white;
    background-color:1e1e1e;
}
```

And here's the testing.php file if that matters

```
<?php

    echo "test page";

?>
```

Comment: Your main page is a `.php` file right?

Comment: try `include __DIR__ . '/test.php';`  . please note that the parenthesis are not needed, but its a style that is copied around so much most people use them.

Comment: please check the file path because code is very simple ... code is correct so one reason for this problem that is path.

Comment: @Briscoooe Yes, if you want to execute php, it needs to be a php file. Change the extension to `.php` and it ought to work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write php code then file extension must be ".php". So change your main HTML file extension to PHP.

Answer (score 2):

First Solution:

If you want to write php code then file extension must be ".php". So change your main HTML file extension to PHP.

Second Solution:

You can tell Apache to treat .html files as PHP by adding a new FilesMatch directive:

```
1. Open C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
2. Search: 
   <FilesMatch "\.php$">
   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
   </FilesMatch>
3. Add those three line:
   <FilesMatch "\.html$">
   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
   </FilesMatch>
```

Third Solution:

You can do it by adding an .htaccess file into your document root that contains:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the response. Secondly what do the FilesMatch directive and .htaaccess files do?

Comment: .htaaccess:
The original purpose of .htaccess—reflected in its name—was to allow per-directory access control.


FilesMatch directive:
Apache to treat files extensions.